# Alternative uniformities on topological groups

Tags: topological-groups, uniform-spaces, coarse-geometry

Are there any interesting alternative uniformities defined on topological groups besides the usual four (left, right, and their meet/join)? I am curious because in the (sort of) dual setting of coarse structures, there is also the group-compact coarse structure.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are interested in but functional analysis is awash with such examples--Banach spaces with norm and weak topology, the various (weak, ultraweak strong, ultrastrong) uniformities on $L(H)$  ($H$ Hilbert) etc. (Every vector space is an (additive) group and every l.c. topology thereon is a group topology).

Comment: (In case you are somewhat interested in discrete groups) Theory of relatively hyperbolic groups and thickness (in sense of Drutu-Kapovich) is usually not written in this terminology, but certain parts of it could be reformulated through exotic uniformity structures. I'm not sure how useful it is, but somewhat extends the theory to the world of cg topological groups and proper actions. (...Well, I'm trying to find applications of slightly different language of "filtered uniformity" for last few months hoping for different proof of Dunwoody's accessibility theorem)

Comment: @terceira I think  the question asks for different uniformities that induce the same topology.

Comment: I should probably edit that out of the question, the since the analogous requirement doesn't exist in the coarse analogy. @terceira, I was thinking of uniformities defined more generically than on topological vector spaces or abelian groups, but those settings might help explain the lack of examples here. In the TVS setting, these uniformities tend to arise via duality with convex bornologies, as explained by the Mackey-Arens Theorem. Without a good duality theory, it might be easier to define coarse structures than uniformities.

Comment: It of course depends on the meaning of "interesting". There is a whole class of cardinal reflections (one for each cardinal) that may be applied to every uniform structure and so in particular to each of the four standard uniform structures on a topological group. They all preserve the topology. The first of these, the _precompact_ _reflection_ $p$, is interesting because it is an open problem whether $p\mathcal{L}=p\mathcal{R}$ implies $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{R}$ (Itzkowitz's problem), where $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$ are the left and the right uniform structure.

Comment: Then there is also the _fine_ _uniformity_, the finest uniform structure compatible with the topology of the group. And for every space of functions on the group (for example, almost periodic, distal, etc) one can take the uniform structure projectively generated by that space --- i.e. the coarsest uniformity for which all those functions are uniformly continuous.